# Prevent duplicate values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

How can i ask the user to reenter again if the value from the PID is already existed in the array ?

**ex:** he enter A then B and he enter A again, then the A he entered from the last will not be accepted because it's already existed.

```
int[] Process = {};
int NumberofProcess = 0; 

String[] PID = new String[10]; //Proces ID


System.out.print("Enter a number of Process from 1 to 10 : ");
    while(bError){
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
            NumberofProcess = scan.nextInt();
        }else{  
            scan.next();
            continue;
        }
            bError = false;

    }
//----------------  Ask for the user to input for the Process id AT and EX ------- 
for(int i=0;NumberofProcess > i;i++){

    System.out.print("Please Enter a ProcessID " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        PID[i] = scan.next(); 

}
```

Comment: You could make a `Set<Integer>` and rely on the return value of `Set.add()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not use an array but a `LinkedHashSet` (assuming you want to preserve input order). Then check using the set's `contains(...)` method or try to add the PID using `add(...)` and check the return value (false if it has not been added, i.e. if it already existed in the set).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a `Set` instead, do as Thomas suggests and use either a normal `HashSet` if the order of the values is not important, and `LinkedHashSet` otherwise.

If you must use an array, use `Arrays.binarySearch' to check if the array already contains the string:

```
String pid = scan.next(); 
if (Arrays.binarySearch(PID, pid) < 0) {
    PID[i] = pid;
}
```

Note: of course you need to import `java.util.Arrays`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create a structure were you would store the PID that user has already put in you system.

Then you should validate every new input, against items in that storage. If you find a collision you just notify user about it and repeat the process until he input valid data or choose to exit.

In Java you can used dedicated data structure called collections, that would speed up the finding process. The simple [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) wild be enough for your needs.

To declare

`Collection<String> storage = new ArrayList<>();`

To use

`boolean wasStored = storage.contains(input);`